# Binding protocol fails to pass conformsToProtocol

Tags: objective-c, xamarin, janrain

Using Xamarin to create a binding library for some external code, I've encountered a problem where despite (as far as I can tell) implementing all of the selectors in a protocol, in Obj-C code, my delegate fails to pass a `conformsToProtocol` check and, as a result, the code doesn't work.

Here's what the Objective-C header file looks like (https://github.com/janrain/jump.ios/blob/master/Janrain/JRCapture/Classes/JRCapture.h):

```
@protocol JRCaptureDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)engageAuthenticationDialogDidFailToShowWithError:(NSError *)error;

- (void)engageAuthenticationDidCancel;

- (void)engageAuthenticationDidSucceedForUser:(NSDictionary *)engageAuthInfo forProvider:(NSString *)provider;

 - (void)engageAuthenticationDidFailWithError:(NSError *)error forProvider:(NSString *)provider;

- (void)captureSignInDidSucceedForUser:(JRCaptureUser *)captureUser
                            status:(JRCaptureRecordStatus)captureRecordStatus;

- (void)captureSignInDidFailWithError:(NSError *)error;

- (void)registerUserDidSucceed:(JRCaptureUser *)registeredUser;

- (void)registerUserDidFailWithError:(NSError *)error;

- (void)refreshAccessTokenDidSucceedWithContext:(id <NSObject>)context;

- (void)refreshAccessTokenDidFailWithError:(NSError *)error context:(id <NSObject>)context;
@end
```

And here's the part of the `ApiDefinition.cs` that corresponds to it:

```
[Model, BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
public partial interface JRCaptureDelegate {

    [Export ("engageAuthenticationDidCancel")]
    void EngageAuthenticationCancelled ();

    [Export ("engageAuthenticationDidSucceedForUser:forProvider:")]
    void AuthenticationSucceededForProvider (NSDictionary engageAuthInfo, string provider);

    [Export ("captureSignInDidSucceedForUser:status:")]
    void SignInSucceeded (JRCaptureUser captureUser, JRCaptureRecordStatus captureRecordStatus);

    [Export ("registerUserDidSucceed:")]
    void  RegisterUserSucceeded(JRCaptureUser registeredUser);

    [Export ("refreshAccessTokenDidSucceedWithContext:")]
    void  RefreshAccessTokenSucceeded(NSObject context);

    //- (void)engageAuthenticationDialogDidFailToShowWithError:(NSError *)error
    [Export ("engageAuthenticationDialogDidFailToShowWithError:")]
    void DialogFailedToShow (NSError error);

    //- (void)engageAuthenticationDidFailWithError:(NSError *)error forProvider:(NSString *)provider;
    [Export("engageAuthenticationDidFailWithError:forProvider:")]
    void AuthenticationFailedForProvider (NSError error, NSString provider);

    //- (void)captureSignInDidFailWithError:(NSError *)error;
    [Export("captureSignInDidFailWithError:")]
    void SignInFailed (NSError error);

    //- (void)registerUserDidFailWithError:(NSError *)error;
    [Export("registerUserDidFailWithError:")]
    void RegisterUserFailed (NSError error);

    //- (void)refreshAccessTokenDidFailWithError:(NSError *)error context:(id <NSObject>)context;
    [Export("refreshAccessTokenDidFailWithError:context:")]
    void RefreshAccessTokenFailed (NSError error, NSObject context);
}
```

This compiles and appears to work just fine except I was having a problem with one particular method that didn't appear to want to call the methods in my delegate class. After *a lot* of digging (and learning Objective-C the hard way), I believe I have isolated the problem. In the library I'm binding, I have this:

```
    if ([delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(JRCaptureDelegate)] &&
        [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(captureSignInDidSucceedForUser:status:)])
```

And with a little `DLog`ing, I find that my delegate fails the `conformsToProtocol` check (although it does pass the `respondsToSelector` check).

So why does my class fail `conformsToProtocol` when it does implement all the methods in the protocol. What am I missing here?

My class implementing the delegate that gets passed to the various methods that take a `JRCaptureDelegate` just looks like this:

```
public class SignIn : JRCaptureDelegate
{
     // overrides for each method
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, think I might have cracked it. I added the `Adopts` attribute to my class (which is vaguely mentioned in various places in the Xamarin documentation, but not really suggested as something to do when creating a binding library). So now I have this:

```
[Adopts("JRCaptureDelegate")] 
public class SignIn : JRCaptureDelegate
{
     // overrides for each method
}
```

And it now passes the `conformsToProtocol` check. I'm not sure why this isn't automatic since I'm implementing the JRCaptureDelegate interface/protocol.

Comment: This is correct, currently we do not automatically respond yes to conformsToProtocol for protocols like this (but we will though).

Comment: This still doesn't appear to be added. Any updates regarding this?